# Setting hover text bg to white in plotlyjs

Tags: d3.js, plotly

Is there anywhere to override the css of plotly js so that you can set the background color of hover texts?

Answer (score -1):

[Issue 102](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/102) of the plotly github project shows that the styling for the tooltips is done with inline styles which only appear on hover in javascript.

[This suggestion](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/102#issuecomment-163713712) from that issue is a possible workaround:

```
graphDiv.on('plotly_hover', function(data) {
  querySelectorAll(".hovertext text").forEach( /* ... */);
  // ...
});
```